# Diagonalize the Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I am trying to diaganolize a matrix. Here is the question I am working on

> If
>   $$ A\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1.5 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and}\quad A \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}, $$
>   build $A = PDP^{-1}$ and calculate $A$.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given information tells you both eigenvectors and eigenvalues: notice that $\left[
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
3\\
\end{array}
\right]$ got scaled by $1/2$ and $\left[
\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right]$ by $-2$.  Now it's just plugging in:

For an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \cdots \mathbf{v}_n$ and associated eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n$, we can write:

$$M = [\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \cdots \mathbf{v}_n] \left[
 \begin{matrix}
  \lambda_1 &    \\
   & \lambda_2  &  \\
   &  & \ddots & \\
   &  &  &  & \lambda_n
 \end{matrix}
\right]
 [ \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \cdots \mathbf{v}_n]^{-1}$$

where the $\mathbf{v}_k$'s are the columns of those two matrices.

Comment: How does this apply to the formula A = PDP^-1?